# Automatic Mouse Mover Start/Stop moving with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, while-loop

I need your help. I wanted as an exercise for clean code and GUI but that doesn't work. In line 65 (method `automaticMouseMoverStart`), depending on whether the stop button was pressed or not, the loop should run. However the robot does not work. No matter if `isPressed` is set to true or false. Does anyone have advice on how I can specifically turn this on and off?

```java
package Übung;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GUIMouseMover extends JFrame {
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel pnlOben;
    private static JButton btnStart;
    private static JToggleButton btnStop;
    public static final int moveafterSecond = 5000;
    public static final int withs = 400;
    public static final int heigth = 400;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                buildAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void buildAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Mouse-Mover");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jpn = new JPanel();
        jpn.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(e -> automaticMouseMoverStart());
        btnStop = new JToggleButton("stop");
        jpn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        jpn.add(btnStart, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jpn.add(btnStop, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(jpn);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void automaticMouseMoverStart() {
        boolean isPressed = btnStop.getModel().isPressed();
        while(isPressed = false) {
            try {
                Robot robot;
                robot = new Robot();
                Random random = new Random();
                while (true) {
                    robot.mouseMove(random.nextInt(heigth), random.nextInt(withs));
                    Thread.sleep(moveafterSecond);
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I am open to comments, criticism and suggestions for improvement. As long as they are not offensive. :D

Comment: you _must not_ sleep the EDT! nor block it with a tight while.. learn about how to use concurrency in swing. Also: static scope is the wrong tool nearly always (certainly here)

Comment: Side note: This is a long way towards clean code :) - As kleopatra already stated static methods and fields are a code smell in many cases. Sure, you need `main()` to be static but that's about it. Look at `GUIMouseMover` extending `JFrame` and ask yourself: "Why did I do this if I never even create an instance of that class?".

Comment: most (major) Swing components have a note: "**Warning:** Swing is not thread safe. For more information see [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)." - please check that link

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [*Swing* timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

```java
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUIMouseMover {
    private static final int  HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final int  WIDTH = 400;
    private static final Random RAND = new Random();

    private JButton  startButton;
    private JButton  stopButton;
    private JPanel  canvas;
    private Robot  robot;
    private Timer  timer;

    public GUIMouseMover() throws AWTException {
        robot = new Robot();
        timer = new Timer(5000, this::automaticMouseMoverStart);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
//        timer.setRepeats(true); <- Default is 'true'.
    }

    private void automaticMouseMoverStart(ActionEvent event) {
        int x = RAND.nextInt(WIDTH);
        int y = RAND.nextInt(HEIGHT);
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, canvas);
        robot.mouseMove(p.x, p.y);
    }

    private void buildAnddisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createStartButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createStopButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void cease(ActionEvent event) {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        timer.stop();
    }

    private void commence(ActionEvent event) {
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private JPanel createCanvas() {
        canvas = new JPanel();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        return canvas;
    }

    private JPanel createStartButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.setMnemonic('a');
        startButton.setToolTipText("Start automatic, random mouse movement.");
        startButton.addActionListener(this::commence);
        panel.add(startButton);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createStopButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.setMnemonic('o');
        stopButton.setToolTipText("Terminate automatic, random mouse movement.");
        stopButton.addActionListener(this::cease);
        panel.add(stopButton);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            GUIMouseMover instance = new GUIMouseMover();
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> instance.buildAnddisplayGui());
        }
        catch (AWTException xAwt) {
            xAwt.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `ActionListener`s, in the above code, are implemented via [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).